# Help needed in finding the area of the square (tricky geometry question)

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

I saw this question posted on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/engineers_feed/status/1576815988615839744?s=20&t=1r8SyTMhJKHJZ6Yr8Vlm-Q), and I can't seem to find the answer to this -

[image: Question]

I am stuck with this puzzle for over 2 hours now.

How would one go about trying to solve this and can anyone explain it in a simple way that anyone can understand.

Comment: Can you link to the tweet?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I closed it over 2 hours ago and have been thinking for myself, I think it should be on World of Engineering page. Let me try to see if I can find it.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I added the tweet link to the question.

Comment: Let side of square is $a$. Area of each rectangle is $\frac{a^2}{5}$. Then width of blue rectangle is $\frac{a}{5}$. Then width of orange rectangle is $\frac{4a}{5}$. Then height of orange rectangle is $\frac{a}{4}$. Then $\frac{a}{4}=4$. Then $a=16$. Then square area is 256.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $A$ be the rectangle comprised of the yellow, green and pink rectangles.
The ratio of {area of orange} to {area of $A$} is $1:3$. So the height of $A$ is $12$.
So the area of the square is $(4+12)^2=256$.

Answer (score 3):

Let the central rectangle's width and height be $w$ and $h$ respectively. Then because all rectangles have the same area

- the yellow rectangle has height $2h$ and hence width $\frac12w$
- the orange rectangle has width $\frac32w$ and hence height $\frac23h=4$ (so $h=6$)
- the blue rectangle has height $\frac83h$ and hence width $\frac38w$

All this is inside a square, so we have the square side as $\frac83h=\left(\frac32+\frac38\right)w=\frac{15}8w=16$. Thus the square's area is $256$ and $w=\frac{64}{45}h=\frac{128}{15}$.